# how to develop regex for a number with php

Tags: php, regex

I want to build a regex with php for a number such as '123 2345 7890'. The first 3 characters should be numbers then space, again 4 characters should be numbers then space, again 4 characters should be numbers then space. So far I have done this but it's not working I mean this does not gives me the actual format that i want, can anyone please help me to sort it.

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4}).*$/", $new_password)
```

Comment: There are no spaces allowed in your regexp...

Comment: `^\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}$`

Comment: @LarsStegelitz how can i do that

Comment: @pavel this doesnot help me `^\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}$`

Comment: Use `\s` for space character

Comment: Whenever you have doubts about why your regular expression isn't matching your string, test it in an online service such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/). It has a detailed explanation of the steps taken while matching your pattern and it can help you identify where you went wrong.

Comment: Read carefully the answers that have been given in the comments, additionnaly, check [preg_match's doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) if you need to, and if this is still not ok for you, please edit your question and provide more details about what's wrong _precisely_ please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not match spaces, and the `.*` at the end optionally matches any character except a newline.

You could use `\h+` to match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars and at the end match optional horizontal whitespace chars `\h*`

Or just   to match a mere space instead.

If you don't need the capture groups for after processing, you could omit them.

```
^\d{3}\h+\d{4}\h+\d{4}\h*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Z3UYH/1)